# looping through plotly r using add_trace

Tags: r, loops, plotly

I am trying to create a scatter/line plot using plotly R and looping through a vector of car manufacturers.  Unfortunately, the plot will only display the last manufacturer value. Could someone please show me where I am going wrong?

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

df <- 
  mpg %>% 
  summarise(avg_displ = mean(displ), .by = c(manufacturer, year)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = manufacturer, values_from = avg_displ)

#list of manufacturers
manf_vec <- colnames(df[-1])

p <- plot_ly(df, type = "scatter", mode = "lines+markers")

for(manf in manf_vec){
  p <- 
    add_trace(p,
              x =~year, 
              y = ~ df[[manf]])
}
p
```

Comment: Possibly a lazy evaluation problem.  Does wrapping your `p <- add_trace(...)` in `force({ ... })` solve the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: I found a link and modified the code to obtain the desired result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54788327/r-plotly-add-trace-within-loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Plotly Add Trace within Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54788327/r-plotly-add-trace-within-loop)